# Tried to use bash arrays but for some reason this fails?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Im trying to make a script that should be executed with crontab, but I'm having difficulties to declare an array an fetch the key and value from that array. (Running MacOS 10.12.6)

This is what i'v got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A listofnames

listofnames[one]="one test"
listofnames[two]="two test"

for val in "${listofnames[@]}"; do
    echo $val
done
```

And this throws me an error: `declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]` and the output it `two test`.

Expected output:

```
$ ./test.sh
one test
two test
```

Comment: Come on, folks…don't downvote without an explanation.

Comment: macOS comes with bash version 3 (for licensing reasons), but associative arrays weren't added to bash until version 4. If you can't do what you need with numerically-indexed arrays, your best bet would be to install bash v4 with [homebrew](https://brew.sh), and then change the shebang line to use it instead of the built-in version.

Comment: What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Nice! Seems that I have bash 5 installed, just changed the shebang and everything works smoothly now.

Answer (score 2):

It's not required that you declare your array upfront, but if you do, you need to use the lowercase "a"—-not the capital.

```
declare -a listofnames
```

Secondly, you need to use numerical indicies when referencing an array element

```
listofnames[one] <----- incorrect
listofnames[1]   <----- correct
```

So, for your two elements, it should look like this:

```
listofnames[1]="one test"
listofnames[2]="two test"
```

Or you assign all values at once, taking care of the first element having index 0

```
listofnames=("" "one test" "two test)
```